Animate height resize on container with dynamic content
I am new to svelte and I was playing with the svelte/animate and svelte/transitions modules. The main question is how to animate container height when new content is added/removed.
I was trying a few approaches using tweened from svelte/motion but I can't seem to find the right solutions unless I do some shenanigans including wrapping div with overflows.
REPL- use the counter to load/unload more elements to see the issue when row gets removed/added
As I said I am quite new to Svelte5. Hence, I am not quite sure if I am using svelte/animate and svelte/transitions correctly, if anyone could give a little bit of explanation on these two and when to use them, it would be greatly appreciated.

Include relevant code in the question, do not just link to it. Show how content is added / removed.

Svelte transitions run when the element is added or removed from the DOM.  Since you want to animate the change of a container that is already there, and is not being removed/re-added, transitions are not the way to go.  They just won't run.
What you need is animation.  Svelte, however, only supports animation with animate:flip.  The animation can only be done on direct children of a keyed {#each} block, however.
I would say that Svelte cannot provide you with the animation tool you are requiring.  Explore alternatives, like plain CSS animation.
